# Two Versions of Controls Referenced when I Only Want One

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I updated my solution to use a new version of Telerik controls for WPF.  Now I notice that there are two versions available when "using" the controls.  I have checked and none of my projects reference the older version of the dlls.  How do I locate and remove the older version?

[image]

Comment: Is it simply a side-by-side installation, and you need to remove the older one?  If VS knows about it, I would suspect it's referenced in a project somewhere.

Comment: That's what I thought, too.  I've checked all projects twice now and the older version isn't referenced; at least from what I can tell.

Comment: I'd  `grep telerik` recursively from the base directory and see where that gets you...

Comment: I have recursively checked the base folder and it's contents.  I cannot find any references to the 2016 version.  I have removed and re-added the references in all projects.  This problem persists!  I'm almost ready to shave my head and become a monk!

Comment: Ok - New discovery and I don't know how to handle it.  All the projects refer to version 2019.1.220.45.  I have checked the "Prerequisites" list on the Publish tab and Telerik is NOT listed.  I have checked the "Application Files" and all Telerik dlls are set to Include/Required/Include.   Now when looking at the actual published .manifest file in the publish destination folder, it lists 3 Telerik dlls as dependencyType="preRequisite" allowDelayedBinding="true" and they have the 2016 version listed.  Now what?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the problem, but I have no idea why this was the cause.

This is a WPF application.  I have a shared .xaml file that sets up styles that are shared by many of the screens.  In the  declaration I noticed a few namespaces that were setup, but not required in the rest of the file.  Here are there definitions:

```
xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView"
```

After removing these to declarations, the resulting manifest no longer shows the 2016 version of Telerik controls as being prerequisites and the application installs properly.

Examining the new declarations in the updated Telerik controls shows the exact same text.  So I'm not sure why this worked.  Unless anyone knows, I'll just chalk this up to one of those mysteries of life that will never have an answer.